# Operator Precedence in Java (bit shift operator) : why is the following output true?

Tags: java, bit-shift, operator-precedence

This may seem to you a very easy question but I am really stuck.

```
e = 16 >> 1 >> 2 % 2 == 8
```

This turns out to be true, but I don't get why. I know that I first do 2%2==0 but then what follows?

Comment: Take a look to [Operators Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: First, take a look at the precedence table: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html, and add parentheses to your expression.  Then we'll talk ;)

Comment: This is an exam question, it was just like that, sorry. And I've already read the precedence rules...

Comment: @Yoana: Ok.  Have you figured out how you can use the precedence rules to add parentheses to an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've said, the `2 % 2` gets evaluated first, leaving `16 >> 1 >> 0 == 8`.  Next comes the first `>>`, and when you right-shift 16 by one bit, you get 8.  So the expression becomes `8 >> 0 == 8`.

The next operator is the remaining `>>`, but now you're right-shifting by zero bits, which of course changes nothing; and the expression is `8 == 8`.  The last operation is `==`, which of course returns `true`.

Note that when you right-shift an integer by one bit, it's the same as halving its value (and rounding down, if the original integer was odd).  Whatever number of bits you right-shift by, you have to halve that many times.  For example, `64 >> 3` is the same as `64 / 2 / 2 / 2` which is 8.

Comment: That was just what I needed!! Thank you for the good example!

Answer (score 4):

`==` is (apart from the assignment `=`) the weakest binding operation, so you have `16 >> 1 >> 0` that is compared to 8, and that is `true`.